# How to add custom HTTP header to the gzipped Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gzip, afnetworking-3

I'm trying to make Post request with custom HTTP header (I'm adding cookies) and here is my code :

```
+ (void)performPostRequestToUrl:(NSString *)url
                 Parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
               CustomHeader:(NSDictionary *)customHeader
                    Success:(SuccessBlock)success
                    Failure:(FailureBlock) failure{
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFgzipRequestSerializer serializerWithSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];

if (customHeader != nil) {
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[customHeader objectForKey:@"value"] forHTTPHeaderField:[customHeader objectForKey:@"key"]];
}

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSDictionary * responseDicionary = responseObject;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseHeader = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    success(responseHeader, responseDicionary);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    //[Flurry logError:@"HTTP POST error" message:error.localizedDescription error:error];
    NSString * message = error.localizedDescription;
    BOOL isTimeOut = NO;
    if(error.code == -1009 || error.code == -1004) {
        message = @"No internet connection!\n Connect to internet and try again";
    }else if (error.code == 3840) {
        message = @"An Error Occurred, Please Try Again Later";
    }
    if(error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
        isTimeOut = YES;
    }
    failure(message, isTimeOut);
    }];
}
```

The Previous Code return this error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myDomain/api/v1/logout, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://myDomain/api/v1/logout}

If I comment this line

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFgzipRequestSerializer serializerWithSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
```

The Code works great!. Notice that I need my request to be gzipped :)

Comment: Looks like the request is working fine, but that your server isn't responding to it correctly. Try using something like http://requestb.in to debug.

Comment: @brandonscript Are you sure I'm doing fine in my code ? Notice that If I keep the AFgzipRequestSerializer and didn't add a custom header the request works fine too.

Comment: In this case, if it compiles, then your code isn't _wrong_ per se. Can't guess what your server is expecting or how it's handling the request. You need to debug the HTTP request - compare a working one to a non-working one in requestbin and figure out what you need to change.

Comment: @brandonscript Thank you so much sir.